# MySQL Xcode 4.2 can't find object

Tags: iphone, mysql, xcode, crash

I use Xcode 4.2.
Following this tutorial http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,51324,127220 I have this warning in the console, and the application crash.

> warning: Could not find object file
>   "/Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-4307905-1321228068.51/release/libmysql/../zlib/libzlib.a(inffast.c.o)"
>   - no debug information available for "/Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-4307905-1321228068.51/mysql-5.5.18/zlib/inffast.c".

the problem it's that hd2 doesn't exist, so why mysql.h library search in this folder? I use mysql 32 bit.

thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is for OS X development and not iOS.
iOS doesn't have MySQL engine, it has sqlite which has only a subset of MySQL commands.